# Jquery change order of existing element while maintaining scroll position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have several sections, each containing a number of articles. The articles have overflowing text with `overflow: scroll`, so each article may have its own scroll position.

Is there any way to reorder the sections without losing their articles' scroll positions?

PS: I actually have to change the DOM structure, not just how it looks.

PPS: I could loop through each section and each article and save them in a variable and then reapply the scroll position to each article. But this feels like a workaround..

```js
$(document).click(function() {
  
  $('section:first-of-type').appendTo('body');
  
})
```

```css
section {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#one { background-color: lightcoral; }
#two { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<section id="one">
  
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit doloribus quos voluptatem, blanditiis perspiciatis consequatur, consectetur totam omnis vero perferendis harum iusto magni recusandae eaque nobis esse aperiam minus cumque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores, nostrum omnis itaque, architecto blanditiis dolor aliquam natus, velit quia optio ipsam fuga voluptate error veniam quas provident doloribus reprehenderit?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit blanditiis, excepturi dolores placeat laborum rerum possimus deserunt eligendi repellendus quasi, sequi obcaecati cum ipsa fugit qui praesentium. Ipsam, similique in.
  </article>

  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit doloribus quos voluptatem, blanditiis perspiciatis consequatur, consectetur totam omnis vero perferendis harum iusto magni recusandae eaque nobis esse aperiam minus cumque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores, nostrum omnis itaque, architecto blanditiis dolor aliquam natus, velit quia optio ipsam fuga voluptate error veniam quas provident doloribus reprehenderit?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit blanditiis, excepturi dolores placeat laborum rerum possimus deserunt eligendi repellendus quasi, sequi obcaecati cum ipsa fugit qui praesentium. Ipsam, similique in.
  </article>
  
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit doloribus quos voluptatem, blanditiis perspiciatis consequatur, consectetur totam omnis vero perferendis harum iusto magni recusandae eaque nobis esse aperiam minus cumque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores, nostrum omnis itaque, architecto blanditiis dolor aliquam natus, velit quia optio ipsam fuga voluptate error veniam quas provident doloribus reprehenderit?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit blanditiis, excepturi dolores placeat laborum rerum possimus deserunt eligendi repellendus quasi, sequi obcaecati cum ipsa fugit qui praesentium. Ipsam, similique in.
  </article>
  
</section>
  
<section id="two">
  
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit doloribus quos voluptatem, blanditiis perspiciatis consequatur, consectetur totam omnis vero perferendis harum iusto magni recusandae eaque nobis esse aperiam minus cumque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores, nostrum omnis itaque, architecto blanditiis dolor aliquam natus, velit quia optio ipsam fuga voluptate error veniam quas provident doloribus reprehenderit?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit blanditiis, excepturi dolores placeat laborum rerum possimus deserunt eligendi repellendus quasi, sequi obcaecati cum ipsa fugit qui praesentium. Ipsam, similique in.
  </article>
  
  <article>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit doloribus quos voluptatem, blanditiis perspiciatis consequatur, consectetur totam omnis vero perferendis harum iusto magni recusandae eaque nobis esse aperiam minus cumque.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis dolores, nostrum omnis itaque, architecto blanditiis dolor aliquam natus, velit quia optio ipsam fuga voluptate error veniam quas provident doloribus reprehenderit?
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit blanditiis, excepturi dolores placeat laborum rerum possimus deserunt eligendi repellendus quasi, sequi obcaecati cum ipsa fugit qui praesentium. Ipsam, similique in.
  </article>
  
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: _Reorder_? Like a drag'n drop?

Comment: Nah, just simply upon a click I want to put the first section at the bottom of the DOM structure. In the example above switch `section#one` and `section#two`

Answer (score 0):

You can save the scrolls positions of your elements by using [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Save then using `map()` into an array

Reorder your elements

And restore the Scroll positions using the array that you saved making a `.each()` in the elements:

```js
$('#swap').click(function() {

    //Simple trick to swap sections
    $(this).toggleClass('active')
    
    //Saves all scroll position's of section 1
    let arrSectionOne = $('#section1 .overflow').map(function(){ return $(this).scrollTop(); }).get();
    
    //Saves all scroll position's of section 2
    let arrSectionTwo = $('#section2 .overflow').map(function(){ return $(this).scrollTop(); }).get();
    
    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
      $("#section1").before($("#section2"));
    else
      $("#section1").after($("#section2"));
      
    //Restore Scroll Positions
    $('#section1 .overflow').each(function(i){
        $(this).scrollTop(arrSectionOne[i]);
    })
    
    $('#section2 .overflow').each(function(i){
        $(this).scrollTop(arrSectionTwo[i]);
    })
    
});
```

```css
.overflow {
  width: 330px;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="section1">
  <div class="overflow" style="border: 1px solid green">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at sem purus. Morbi ullamcorper nisi vitae nunc fermentum, quis hendrerit orci maximus. Cras malesuada auctor nibh, egestas aliquet enim tincidunt dictum. Maecenas enim lectus, fermentum
    eu massa a, malesuada egestas dui. Ut egestas velit eros, eu pulvinar metus bibendum ut. Aenean est justo, dictum eget ultricies eget, fermentum eu ex. Aliquam mollis sem in hendrerit malesuada. Praesent non enim molestie sapien laoreet pharetra sed
    eget diam. Vivamus placerat sem sed tortor lobortis, iaculis rhoncus purus condimentum. Nullam imperdiet nisi sit amet risus faucibus, vitae ultrices lectus aliquam.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="section2">
  <div class="overflow" style="border: 1px solid red">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at sem purus. Morbi ullamcorper nisi vitae nunc fermentum, quis hendrerit orci maximus. Cras malesuada auctor nibh, egestas aliquet enim tincidunt dictum. Maecenas enim lectus, fermentum
    eu massa a, malesuada egestas dui. Ut egestas velit eros, eu pulvinar metus bibendum ut. Aenean est justo, dictum eget ultricies eget, fermentum eu ex. Aliquam mollis sem in hendrerit malesuada. Praesent non enim molestie sapien laoreet pharetra sed
    eget diam. Vivamus placerat sem sed tortor lobortis, iaculis rhoncus purus condimentum. Nullam imperdiet nisi sit amet risus faucibus, vitae ultrices lectus aliquam.
  </div>
</div>


<button id="swap">
  Swap it!
</button>
```